# Elixir map returns nil

Tags: elixir

I want to perform a simple mapping of a given charlist

```
def encode(str) do
  map = %{
    'A' => '1',
    'B' => '2',
    'C' => '3',
    'D' => '4'
  }

  Enum.map(str, fn char -> map[char] end)
end
```

When I run this I get a list of nil values.

```
encode('ABCD') # [nil, nil, nil, nil]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: FWIW, `Enum.map(str, fn char -> map[[char]] end)` would work with your initial map :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`'A'` is a list itself, containing a single char.

```rb
is_list('A')
#⇒ true
'A' ++ 'B' ++ 'C' ++ 'D'
#⇒ 'ABCD'
```

What you need instead as map keys, are *chars*, not *lists*.

```rb
map = %{
  ?A => '1',
  ?B => '2',
  ?C => '3',
  ?D => '4'
}

Enum.map('ABCD', fn char -> map[char] end)
# or Enum.map('ABCD', &map[&1])
#⇒ ['1', '2', '3', '4']
```